# Correct usage of PowerShell foreach command

Tags: powershell, foreach, foreach-object

```
$report = @()foreach ($vm in Get-View -ViewType Virtualmachine){ $vms = "" | Select-Object VMName, Hostname, IPAddress, OS, Boottime, VMState, TotalCPU, CPUAffinity, CPUHotAdd, CPUShare, CPUlimit, OverallCpuUsage, CPUreservation, TotalMemory, MemoryShare, MemoryUsage, MemoryHotAdd, MemoryLimit, MemoryReservation, Swapped, Ballooned, Compressed, TotalNics, ToolsStatus, ToolsVersion, HardwareVersion, TimeSync, CBT, Portgroup, VMHost, Datastore, Notes, FaultTolerance $vms.VMName = $vm.Name $vms.Hostname = $vm.guest.hostname $vms.IPAddress = $vm.guest.ipAddress $vms.OS = $vm.Config.GuestFullName $vms.Boottime = $vm.Runtime.BootTime $vms.VMState = $vm.summary.runtime.powerState $vms.TotalCPU = $vm.summary.config.numcpu $vms.CPUAffinity = $vm.Config.CpuAffinity $vms.CPUHotAdd = $vm.Config.CpuHotAddEnabled $vms.CPUShare = $vm.Config.CpuAllocation.Shares.Level $vms.TotalMemory = $vm.summary.config.memorysizemb $vms.MemoryHotAdd = $vm.Config.MemoryHotAddEnabled $vms.MemoryShare = $vm.Config.MemoryAllocation.Shares.Level $vms.TotalNics = $vm.summary.config.numEthernetCards $vms.OverallCpuUsage = $vm.summary.quickStats.OverallCpuUsage $vms.MemoryUsage = $vm.summary.quickStats.guestMemoryUsage $vms.ToolsStatus = $vm.guest.toolsstatus $vms.ToolsVersion = $vm.config.tools.toolsversion $vms.TimeSync = $vm.Config.Tools.SyncTimeWithHost $vms.HardwareVersion = $vm.config.Version $vms.MemoryLimit = $vm.resourceconfig.memoryallocation.limit $vms.MemoryReservation = $vm.resourceconfig.memoryallocation.reservation $vms.CPUreservation = $vm.resourceconfig.cpuallocation.reservation $vms.CPUlimit = $vm.resourceconfig.cpuallocation.limit $vms.CBT = $vm.Config.ChangeTrackingEnabled $vms.Swapped = $vm.Summary.QuickStats.SwappedMemory $vms.Ballooned = $vm.Summary.QuickStats.BalloonedMemory $vms.Compressed = $vm.Summary.QuickStats.CompressedMemory $vms.Portgroup = Get-View -Id $vm.Network -Property Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name $vms.VMHost = Get-View -Id $vm.Runtime.Host -property Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name $vms.Datastore = $vm.Config.DatastoreUrl[0].Name $vms.Notes = $vm.Config.Annotation $vms.FaultTolerance = $vm.Runtime.FaultToleranceState $Report += $vms } $Report = $Report | Sort-Object VMName
IF ($Report -ne "") {
$report | Export-Csv -path vm.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

I'm trying to create a report to run against our virtual machines and can't get my head around what I'm doing wrong with the foreach (or foreach-object) command. It shows the following error in VSCODE **"Unexpected token 'foreach' in expression or statement" **

I'm sure it's something dumb so any help or comments on the error or improving the script on general would be gratefully received.

I have searched other similar questions but none stood out to me as the answer.

ps. I realize the code looks untidy - something to do with the copy/paste - sorry about that.

Comment: Try putting a line break between ```$report = @()``` and ```foreach``` in the first line of your sample code…

Comment: $Report = $Report should be inside curly brackets.

Comment: What's the @() thing before the foreach?

Comment: Could you make all the code fit in the window?

Comment: The code has a lot of missing line breaks and makes no sense.

Comment: Hi all and thanks for responding. 
@mclayton thanks adding that line break resolved that particular error, however there further beyond that first error. 
@ everyone else - agreed the script was really not well written or formatted. 
Luckily I am able to stand on the shoulders of giants and found an alternative script on Tech Republic https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-gather-your-vcenter-inventory-data-with-this-vmware-powershell-script/ which works a treat. 
Thanks for your input and have a great day :-)